# how to call a different methods from JavaScript file in rails controller method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have **firebase-auth.js**

```js
    function sendCode(phoneNumber) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (confirmationResult) {
          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // Error; SMS not sent
          // ...
        });
    }
```

i want to call the method `sendCode(phoneNumber)` in rails controller method `def verify_code()`.

Comment: your javascript it's code that will run into your client, not in your server

Answer (score 1):

another way to think about it is that the javascript `sendCode` function you have here is probably being called AFTER a request has hit the server.

The request that hits the server is what will hit the Rails-side method `verify_code` (it will do this because it will hit a unique endpoint that will know which controller & action to route to). It will then RESPOND with a simple http status of 200. Or maybe it will respond with a json resule like

result:
 {success: ok}

or maybe it will respond with a blank HTML page. It doesn't matter what the Rails-side controller responds as, in modern apps you typically will be calling your subsequent `sendCode` from **Javascript promise**, like a then() clause

For example, a typical Ajax request might look like:

```
fetch('http://yourdomain.com/api/xyi').then((result) => {
  // use the results here, if there are any
})
```

In your case, maybe the result contains the phone number that would get passed to your front end code sendCode

```
fetch('http://yourdomain.com/api/xyi').then(({phoneNumber} = result) => {
  // phone number was destructured out of results
  sendCode(phoneNumber)
})
```

what's important here is that the sendCode function only gets called after the Ajax request has returned successfully

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have verify_code.js.erb file which will respond to js in your controller action. You can't call/write js code in controller action. Then inside this verify code js file you can call that chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually taken the wrong direction.